# Some questions about proving with induction

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

I have a good understanding of how to use induction, but these two proof are really puzzling me.

1)Use mathematical induction to prove that for every positive integer $n$
greater than $23$, there exist nonnegative integers $x$ and $y$ for which $n = 7x + 5y.$

For this one. Do I have to do anything with the $x$ and $y$? I know I need to show $n+1$ is true but am I suppose to rewrite $n = 7x + 5y$ to something like $n+1 = 7x + 5y+1$ and use the induction hypothesis to plug that in for $n+1$ in $n+1>23$?

2) Prove that given any integer $n > 1$, there is a power of $2$ that is bigger than $\frac{n}{2}$ and less than or equal to $n$.

This one wasn't specified that it can be done by induction, but I am pretty sure it can be. (I hope) I am thinking the inequality should look like this $n \ge 2^n> \frac{n}{2}$ but how can $n\ge 2^n$ be true when $n > 1$?

Comment: For part one, assume $n$ can indeed be written as $n=5x+7y$ for some $x$ and $y$. Then you wish to write $n+1=(5x+7y)+1$ in the same form. The key is to write 1 in terms of linear combinations of 5 and 7. This is indeed doable since gcd(5,7)=1.

Comment: The second one is supposed to be $\frac n2 \lt 2^x \lt n$

Comment: For part 2, the questions just asserts that there exists a power of 2. i.e. $2^m$ for some nonnegative integer $m$. It doesnt have to be $n$

Comment: For no. 1), recall that $1=3\cdot 5-2\cdot 7$, so $n+1=5(x+3)+7(y-2)$ and that $1=3\cdot 7-4\cdot 5$, so $n+1=5(x-4)+7(y+3)$ etc.

Comment: You show a *different* x,y work for $n $.  If you like:  if $n=7x_n+5x_n $ then n+1=7x_n+5 x_n +3*5-2*7=7 (x_n-2)+5 (y_n+3)=7x_{n+1}+5x-{n+1} $ where $x-{n+1}=x_n-2$ and $y_{n+1}=y_n+3$.  Except... well, you'll have to work out what happens if $x_n\le 2$.

Comment: For 1 once you figure out the linear combination for n+1 is that it? I have proved n+1>23? and for 2 can I have a hint on what I am suppose to do, This is my first time seeing a problem like that. I Don't get how I am suppose to get the n to n+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove the first one using strong induction.  Just note explicitly that
$$
24 = 2\cdot 7 + 2 \cdot 5,\\
25 = 0\cdot 7 + 5 \cdot 5,\\
26 = 3 \cdot 7 + 1\cdot 5,\\
27 = 1 \cdot 7 + 4\cdot 5,\\
28 = 4\cdot 7 + 0 \cdot 5;
$$
then for any $n\ge 29$, using the assumption that $n-5=5x+7y$ (since $n-5$ is larger than $23$), $n$ is equal to $5(x+1)+7y$.

Answer (score 0):

The key for the first one is to  note that $$24=2(5)+2(7)$$

Now if true for $n$ we have $n=5x+7y $ and we like to express $n+1$ as a combination of $5$ and $7$.

Note that we have $$3(7)-4(5) =1$$ and also $$ 3(5)-2(7) =1$$

Thus if you have two sevens in your $n$ you trade it with three fives,so you have your $n+1$ covered with fives and sevens.

Otherwise since your $n$ is at least $24$ you have at least four fives to trade with three sevens and cover $n+1$ with fives and sevens.

The second one seems manageable and you can get it.

Comment: For the second one I have been doing something thinking and I think it would be easier by contradiction. So would the contradiction of the statement go something like. "Prove that given any integer n > 1, for all powers of 2 will be less than n/2 and greater than or equal to n"?

Comment: Is it true for n=8?

Comment: no? because 2^8 (which is 258) is not less than 8/2 (which is 4).

Comment: @George  Note that a power of $2$ does not mean $2^n$, it simply means $2^k$ for some positive integer $k$. For example if n=$20$, then $2^4$ is between $10$ and $20$.

Comment: oh whoops my mistake, but wouldn't the negation of the statement led to a disjunction? So if I can prove that disjunction false I will prove the beginning statement?

Comment: Yes if you can show the negation does not happen then the original is proved.

Answer (score 0):

Base Case:

If $n=24$  then if we set $x_{24}=2;y_{24}=2$  We $n=24=7x_{24}+y_{24} $

Induction case:

$1=-2*7+3*5=3*7-4*5$

So if $n=7x_n+5y_n $ then

$n+1=7 (x_n-2)+5 (y_n+3)=7(x_n+3)+5(y_n-4) $.

So if $x_n\ge 2$ then you can let $x_{n+1}=x_n-2;y_{n+1}=y_n+3$.  Or if $y_n\ge 4$ you can let $x_{n+1}=x_n+3;y_{n+1}=y_n-4$.

But if $x_n <2$ and $y_n <4$ you can't do either.  But that can't happen if $n\ge 24$. (Because $1*7+3*5=22 <24$)